# Extract URL from order note and add it only to order completed email in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I've searched around here and some posts helped me almost nailing this problem:

My parcel company adds an order note to the order including text and a tracking url for the package. And after that they put the order on completed.

This URL needs to be added to the order completed mail to the customer.

This code is working but only if I send the order completed mail manually:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'woo_add_order_notes_to_email' );
function woo_add_order_notes_to_email() {
    global $woocommerce, $post;
    $args = array(
        'post_id'   => $post->ID,
        'status'    => 'approve',
        'type'      => 'order_note'
    );
    $notes = get_comments( $args );

    if ( $notes ) {
        foreach( $notes as $note ) {
            $notecontent = $note->comment_content;

            if( preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]+:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z;.\/?:@=_#&%~,+$-]+/', $notecontent, $matches) != 0 ) {

                echo '<p>You can follow your order via this link: <a href = "' . $matches[0] . '">' . $matches[0] . '</a></p>';

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you guys can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using wrong hook.

You can do the same thing with this hook 'woocommerce_email_order_meta'. It will resolve your issue.

here is the code example

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', 'woo_add_order_notes_to_email' );

function woo_add_order_notes_to_email( $order, $sent_to_admin = false, $plain_text = false ) {
  /*Do something here to add with order completion email */ 
}
```

Comment: Hi Nishad, thank you for your comment, but this only changes the place of the note to the order meta part (under the table).